# Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, redmine, redmine-plugins

I get the following error after installing plugins to Redmine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The website displays:

> "We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

The error is:

> "Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"

The log is:

```
App 7302 stdout: 
App 7302 stdout: 
[ 2017-05-18 17:18:04.7070 6519/7fc7b81af700 App/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/: An error occured  w hile starting up the preloader.
 Error ID: 5031bd31
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error.l3kNMa
  Message from application: <p>It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:</p   >

  <pre class="commands">bundle install</pre>

<p>If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:</p>

<ol>
  <li>Is this app supposed to be run as the <code>daemon</code> user?</li>
  <li>Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
      see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.</li>
</ol>

<p>-------- The exception is as follows: -------</p>
Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
<pre>  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `map!&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:80:in `materialize&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `specs&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in `specs_for&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:224:in `requested_specs&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.14.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:278:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:381:in `running_bundler&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `&lt;module:App&gt;&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `&lt;module:PhusionPassenger&gt;&#39;
  /opt/redmine-3.3.3-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.6/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `&lt;main&gt;&#39;</pre>


[ 2017-05-18 17:18:04.7174 6519/7fc7b99f3700 age/Hel/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 4-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 5031bd31. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you SSH into your server? if so, try to run:
`
$ bundle install
$ bundle show i18n
`
And tell us what do you get

Comment: try this in cmd line `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin` Helped me out.

Comment: `$ bundle install` still works fine.  When I run `$ bundle show i18n`, I get `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0` . `bundle exec rake rails:update:bin` gives me an error, `Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the plugin that I was trying to install is not compatible with the version of Redmine that I was running.

I did a full migration of a Redmine instance from AWS to a local server, and everything is working properly.  I had the plugin installed on the AWS version, and after doing a migration to the local server, Redmine works, as well as the plugin.

I got the issue above after trying to install the plugin directly to the local server without doing the migration, but it works fine if I just migrate everything from AWS to the local server.

See [this topic](https://community.bitnami.com/t/moving-redmine-data-from-amazon-ec2-to-private-server/49317).